# Querying sql database

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

my currently applications goal is to pull information read-only process from the sql database. And project it Through The iOS application. I'm currently having trouble just to establish a communications and am not sure where abouts to start.

Button Located on : ViewController.cs

```
IList<string> NameList = new List<string>();
string connectionString = "Server=******;Database=******;User Id=******;Password=********
try
{
     IDbConnection dbcon;
     using (dbcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
          bcon.Open();
          using (IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand())
          {
              string sql = "Select * from people";
              dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
              using (IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
              {
                  while (reader.Read())
                  {
                      string FirstName = reader["ForeName"].ToString();
                      NameList.Add(FirstName);
                  }
              reader.Close();
              dbcon.Close();
              title.Text = NameList.FirstOrDefault();
           }    
      }

}
catch
{
```

I've test the connection string outside of the iOS and in a different visual studio only environment and it worked completely. I also read there's an alternative method, I was told I shouldn't be trying to query on the UI of the iOS app and I should use a webserver but I have no idea how to start that task with an sql server.

Error I get:

{System.NotSupportedException: CodePage 1252 not supported
    at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding (Int32 codepage) [0x0015d] in            /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Text/Encoding.cs:479 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.TdsCharset.GetEncodingFromSortOrder (Int32 sortId) [0x00015] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/TdsCollation.cs:316 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.TdsCharset.GetEncodingFromSortOrder (System.Byte[] collation) [0x00007] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/TdsCollation.cs:310 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.TdsCharset.GetEncoding (System.Byte[] collation) [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/TdsCollation.cs:288 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.ProcessEnvironmentChange () [0x0024f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/Tds.cs:1650 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.ProcessSubPacket () [0x0011f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/Tds.cs:1806 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.NextResult () [0x0004a] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/Tds.cs:641 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds.SkipToEnd () [0x00005] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/Tds.cs:714 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds70.Connect (Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionParameters connectionParameters) [0x005b5] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/Tds70.cs:390 
  at Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds80.Connect (Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionParameters connectionParameters) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds/Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol/Tds80.cs:87 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open () [0x001a9] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs:566 }
    base: {System.SystemException}

Comment: I assume you get an exception when trying to connect? If so then add it to your question.

Comment: Please do not do this.  Directly accessing your db server from a remote client over an open channel is incredibly insecure and a horrible idea.  WebServices are generally the best way to setup communication between a client and a db server.

Comment: @Jason I did say I knew about these issues, Just not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Fair enough, are you using the Business Edition of Xamarin.iOS?  What errors/exceptions are you getting when you do this?

Comment: Yes I'm Using Business Edition, Posted the super long Error :s

Comment: @Jason Hey Jason do you think you can refer me to webservices I should Look up or tutorials I can use to develop a better Read Only Connection.

Comment: that error sounds like something in your data is using a non-standard encoding that mono doesn't support.

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

Comment: If anyone Is interested, you have to set Internalization to the area you are from. I chose west and it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from http://bartwullems.blogspot.ca/2013/04/xamarinios-solving-codepage-1252-not.html

Go to the Project Settings of your project in Xamarin Studio.
Go to the Build Tab and select the iOS Build option.
Check the west checkbox in the Internationalization codesets list.